# Accessing subdocument properties in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using a MEAN stack to build this application.

Here is my subject.js schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;
var topics = require('./topic');

var subjectSchema = new schema({
    _category : {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    topics: [topics.schema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Subject', subjectSchema);
```

and my topics.js schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;
var otherstuff = require('./otherstuff');
var otherstuff2 = require('./otherstuff2');

var topicSchema = new schema ({
    title: String,
    otherstuff: [mongoose.model('otherstuff').schema],
    otherstuff2: [mongoose.model('otherstuff2').schema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Topic', topicSchema);
```

What I am having difficulty with is how to access my topicSchema to populate it with forms from my front end.

I can save information to the subjectSchema, but not the sub documents.

I have tried using this as outlined in another article:

```
var Subject = mongoose.model('Subject', subjectSchema);

Subject.find({}).populate('subjects[0].topics[0].title').exec(function(err, subjects) {
    console.log(subjects[0].topics[0].title);
});
```

But I continue to get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`. How do I access the title property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`populate` in `mongoose` is used to populate referenced documents, that are marked with `ref` attribute (see more info in the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)). Sub-documents on the other hand are available when do a simple query because they are actually an array of custom objects, so if you remove the `populate` method your query will work as expected:

```
Subject.find({}).exec(function(err, subjects) {
    console.log(subjects[0].topics[0].title);
});
```

Comment: I did this and I am still getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined. If I remove .title I don't get an error.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a value for the `title` in your database?

Comment: It's in my schema. I am trying to set this up so I can save values to title.

Comment: Well, do you have the topics subdocument at all then? If no, then you need to create it first and then run `find` query on it to get something

Comment: If I understand correctly my topics.js is the subdoc.  I am somewhat new to this. Where would I put the find query?

Comment: Do you have any values inside the topics? If no, then first you need to crate a document containing this sub-documents

Comment: I have topics.js which is my subdocument. Currently it is just an empty schema as outlined above. The values would be populated by an input form on the public facing side of the app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67736/discussion-between-gjanden-and-vsevolod-goloviznin).